# Could not get junit.jar ... Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

При построении проекта (дефолтного, без каких либо своих наработок) выдаёт ошибку:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.  Could not
>   download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
>
> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>
> d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net

Comment: Это из за интернет соединения. Проверьте соединение или прокси. должно быть оттуда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта

1й

1. Нажмите правую кнопку в проекте. (application/project)
2. Открыть *module settings*
3. Вкладка *Dependencies*
4. тут найдите **junit:junit:4.12**
5. нажмите правую кнопку и Удалите его

2й вариант

Проверьте интернет соединение или прокси. Может из за канала он не может скачивать

Comment: Спасибо большое, первый вариант помог!

Comment: @DeathCookies если ответ правильный, выберите "Правильный ответ" что бы другие тоже могли пользоватся, спасибо http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer